# Is $k[x,y]/(x,y) \cong k$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and consider the $k[x,y]$-module $k[x,y]/(x,y)$.

By the Nullstellensatz, $(x,y)$ is a maximal ideal of $k[x,y]$, hence $k[x,y]/(x,y)$ is a field. From this, I would like to infer $k[x,y]/(x,y) \cong k$ (as rings!). Am I correct?

Also, this would imply that the $k[x,y]$-module $k[x,y]/(x,y)$ is simply $k$ considered as a $k[x,y]$-module, right?

Thank you

Comment: This is much easier than you are making it; all you need is the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: Just to emphasise, you could replace $k$ here by any ring and the same would be true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check that the map $k[x,y]\to k$ given by $f\mapsto f(0,0)$ (i.e. evaluate each polynomial at $x=0$ and $y=0$) is a surjective homomorphism of rings with kernel $(x,y)$, so it induces an isomorphism $k[x,y]/(x,y)\cong k$.

If you let $k[x,y]$ act on $k$ such that constants act by multiplication, and $x\cdot\lambda=y\cdot\lambda=0$ for all $\lambda\in k$, then the map above is also a homomorphism of $k[x,y]$ modules, and you get the same conclusion.